# Pseudoinverse of column submatrix, from pseudoinverse of entire matrix.

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, linear-algebra

Hello,

I am working on a numerical method for the least-squares solution of a linear system.  I know that I can approximate the solution to $Ax=b$ with $x=A^+b$, where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$.  In my method, I have to solve such a linear system repeatedly, where the matrices I need to (pseudo)invert are column subsets of a common matrix.

So my question is: Suppose I know the pseudoinverse of $A$ ($A$ is not invertible).  Suppose $B$ is another matrix, whose columns are columns of $A$ (a subset, but not permuted).  Is there an efficient way to compute the pseudoinverse of $B$ from that of $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: How about the case that $B$ is just one column of $A$? 

Comment: Even for that simple case, I cannot see a relationship between the pseudoinverses of $A$ and $B$.  I can certainly compute them, but I don't see any way to get one from the other.

Comment: you're basically asking for the solution $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_N)$ with the constraint $x_1=x_2=...x_n=0$ ($1<n<N$), given the unconstrained solution; this seems hardly possible.